# create Unicode pdf file contain Bangla letter using iText in java

Tags: java, unicode, itext, netbeans-7

I have to generate pdf file using iText in Netbeans IDE. The pdf may contain bangla letter. I already generate pdf file with Bangla letters. But the problem is Bangla letters are not in correct form.

Suppose I have to show: বরিশাল -- But pdf generate: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/abwOV.jpg
Suppose I have to show: পড়ি -- But pdf generate: পড় ি

My code to generate this file:

```
    Document document = new Document();

    BaseFont unicode = BaseFont.createFont("c:/windows/fonts/NikoshBan.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
    Font font = new Font(unicode);

    PdfWriter writer=PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("TableDat.pdf")); 

    document.open();

    document.add(new Paragraph("বরিশাল",font));

    document.close();
```

Comment: You can try using Unicode representation rather than just copy-pasting the Bengali text. Check [this](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0980.pdf). Also, I would suggest using the Vrinda font, as it completely supports bengali text.

Comment: I'm not sure this fix is applied to the latest version of iText, but give it a try:
[Making iText work with Indic scripts](http://puretech.paawak.com/2012/12/22/making-itext-work-with-indic-scripts/)